# Converted charAt() doesnt equals to the same String

Tags: java, string, boolean, equals, charat

My problem is hidden in next code:

```
public class saturo { 
     public String primer, d;
     public void start() {
         primer = "545640";
         //d = "0";
         d = String.valueOf(primer.charAt(((primer.length())-1)));

         if(d == "0"){
             System.out.println("This is equal: d == " + d);
         }else{
             System.out.println("This is not equal: d == " + d);
         }
         }
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            new saturo().start();
        } 
    }
```

So as you see, the problem is that if i declare String d as "0" than the program will execute it as d is equal to "0" and return `true`;

But if i get character "0" from a String, convert it to String, and check if this equals to "0" then i have got a `false`.

I have checked if there is something wrong with character encode, but not, its right in any case. No type mismatches.

Where in this the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare the value of 2 strings, you need to use `.equals()`

So you would do:

```
if(d.equals("0"){
 // your code here
}
```

Using `==` compares the strings by reference (same spot in memory) where `.equals()` compares the value of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

use .equals not == you are comparing by reference not value